# Binding list of objects to WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, itemssource

I have a list of objects which i want to bind to a ListView control in my WPF application.
The Objects have a DataTemplate already, so no need to define that.
The list of objects is a property in the codebehind file in the format `list<object>`
When i add one object programatically, it appears fine. But when i try to bind the ItemSource of the ListBox to the list of objects, nothing shows up.
I am using the following binding:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Portfolios}"/>
```

where the name of the property i am trying to bind to is Portfolios and exists on the parent window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<>` objects don't automatically report when a new item is added. Try using an `ObservableCollection<>` instead, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! that worked wonders. Will post as answer as soon as i am permitted :)